# ACF checkbox - translate

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I need to translate 3 value in a checkbox acf option.

The problem is i have already create my 200 woocommerce products and if i translate in backoffice (acf), i have to change the translate value in each product.

I'm looking for a solution with php.

```
<?php // gout_interne ( value )
        $gout_interne_array = get_field( 'gout_interne' );
        if ( $gout_interne_array ):
        foreach ( $gout_interne_array as $gout_interne_item ):
        echo $gout_interne_item;
        endforeach;
        endif; ?>
```

Values for example are : red, white, blue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `wpml_translate_single_string` filter ([documentation](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_translate_single_string/)):

```
foreach ( $gout_interne_array as $gout_interne_item ) {
    $translated_value = apply_filters( 'wpml_translate_single_string', 
                                        $gout_interne_item, 
                                        'custom_fields_user', 
                                        '[custom_fields_user]gout_interne' );
    echo $translated_value;
}
```

Comment: thx but doesn't work. i cannot find the value in wpml string translator.

Comment: @microb14 Try to scan the plugin/theme where this code is ([documentation](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/string-translation/finding-strings-that-dont-appear-on-the-string-translation-page/)) or "track where strings appear on the site" section of the same doc.